# Remove number from list in which difference between two number are less then specific number

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = [2, 5, 6, 12, 21, 25, 32, 41]
```

This is my `list` and I want to remove all the numbers which are not in difference of 7.

Comment: Can you please share the output of the above list.

Comment: This is I want the output: a = [2, 12, 21,32,41]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before diving into the answers, let's go over what we're dealing with.

You got a list 'A', which you need to loop through to get a **list of numbers that are greater than the previous value + 7**

If you boil down the question, you get left with two main goals

- We need a loop
- and we have a list with the final answer

There are two generic ways of approaching this question. In a loop, we populate a new list. The second way is to manipulate the original list.
Although the First approach requires additional memory, I'll be using the First approach for simplicity.

```
a = [2, 5, 6, 12, 21, 25, 32, 41]     # your original list
b = []           # Empty list that will contain final product

for i in range(len(a)):
    if len(b) == 0:       # if the list is empty, we add first item from 'a' (In our example, it'll be 2)
        b.append(a[i])
    else:
        if a[i] > b[len(b)-1]+7 or a[i] < b[len(b)-1]-7:   # for every value of a, we compare the last digit from list b
            b.append(a[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I have understood your question, in your output list, only those elements should be there whose sum is 7. So that can be achieved by

```
i=1;
while i<len(a):
    if(a[i]-a[i-1] < 7):
        a.remove(a[i])
    else:
        i+=1
print(a)
```

Comment: This is I want the output:

Comment: This is I want the output:  a = [2, 12, 21,32,41]

Comment: My question is, a difference between any two number should be greater than 7.

Comment: this gives output [2, 6, 12, 21, 32, 41], here difference between 2, 6 is 4 and 6 to 12 is 6

Comment: I am not exactly getting what you wany. You want the difference in consecutive elements or any element in the list.

Comment: Each number should compare to the next number if less than 7 then remove it.

Comment: the difference in consecutive elements